# Display ArrayList from SQLite database in logs

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite, android-log

How I can display items from ArraylIst in Logs?

I have class **DataBaseAdapter**, where I have Method *getCardsArrayList*, now I want to display each item from this ArrayLIst in Logs

When I try to write this lines in my **MainActivity**:

```
ArrayList<Cards> cards= dataBaseAdapter.getCardsArrayList();
    for(int i=0; i<cards.size();i++){
        Log.i("WORKS",cards[i]);

    }
```

I have an error: Array type expected, found java.util.ArrayList`<com.myproject.Cards>`

**Cards** is my class with getters and setters

Arrayist in **DataBaseAdapter**:

```
public ArrayList<Cards> getCardsArrayList(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(helper.QUERY,null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i ++){
        cardsArrayList.add(new Cards(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3)));

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return cardsArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this:

```
ArrayList<Cards> cards= dataBaseAdapter.getCardsArrayList();
    for(int i=0; i<cards.size();i++){
        Log.i("WORKS",cards.get(i).toString());

    }
```

To access the items of the arrayList you must use get method.

And just to make sure the Cards class items must have a toString method implemented because the Log needs a String object as the second parameter.

Comment: you're welcome :)
mark it as the answer then. please :)